Derivative of investment with respect to capital
I am trying to understand the meaning and interpretation of dI/dK in economics, i.e. the partial derivative of investment with respect to capital.
What is the significance of the sign of this derivative? Is it usually assumed to be positive or negative or both and why or under which conditions? What does such an assumption of the sign imply? Are there papers in which the sign of this derivative has been ascertained empirically or has been assumed for ODE models? So far, I could only find that Kaldor (1940) assumed that dI/dK < 0.
